# Grand Total text Missing from AMOS Business Suite

Tags: powerbuilder, amos

My report shows perfectly except GRAND TOTAL. Grand total is a computed field but when data shows, this field with its text is cut off and on next page only line below this field shows.

This shows grand total on Powerbuilder but not AMOS

ANY IDEAS?

Tc

Answer (score 0):

It can be solved if you put a nested report that contains your grand total value.